# Does the min-entropy $H_{\rm min}(X)\equiv \min_x\log(1/p_x)$ of a source $X$ have an operational interpretation?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, entropy, renyi-entropy

This is a more specific version of [this other related question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4514923/173147).
Going for example with the notation used in ([Renner 2006](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4514923/173147)), min- and max-entropies of a source $X$ with probability distribution $P_X$ are defined as
$$H_{\rm max}(X) \equiv \log|\{x : \,\, P_X(x)>0\}| = \log|\operatorname{supp}(P_X)|, \\
H_{\rm min}(X) \equiv \min_x \log\left(\frac{1}{P_X(x)}\right)
= -\log \max_x P_X(x).$$

As mentioned in [the comments of the linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4514923/whats-the-rationale-behind-the-definitions-of-min-and-max-entropies#comment9481701_4514923), $H_{\rm max}(X)$ can be interpreted as the optimal bound for compressibility in the single-shot regime.

Is there any similar kind of operational interpretation for the *min* entropy $H_{\rm min}(X)$? Be it in terms of single-shot compressibility, or something else?
I haven't found something like this mentioned directly in the relevant literature, but I might have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Well $P_{max}=\max_{x} P(x)$ is the probability that an optimal guessor given a single guess for the discrete random variable with pmf $(P(x))_{x \in A}$ succeeds. The log measures the number of bits of information obtained in that scenario.

This is classical, also see Wikipedia:

Claude Shannon's definition of *self-information* was chosen to meet several axioms:

- An event with probability 100% is perfectly unsurprising and yields no information.
- The less probable an event is, the more surprising it is and the more information it yields.
- If two independent events are measured separately, the total amount of information is the sum of the self-informations of the individual events.

It can be shown that there is a unique function of probability that meets these three axioms, namely $\log(1/ P(x)).$

Comment: that makes sense, thanks. Unfortunately, the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-entropy) is a bit messy right now, confusing quantum and classical results. I guess what I was mostly looking for is some sort of unifying way to interpret $H_{\rm min}$ and $H_{\rm max}$. As of now, $H_{\rm max}$ tells you about compressibility, while $H_{\rm min}$ about guessing the input. Both seem to be trivially optimal bounds though, so maybe this is as much as we can say

Comment: yes, they are trivially optimum as you point out. you may find a paper by Merhav  interesting, they examine bounds on Shannon entropy for a fixed p_max.  I cannot find the reference right now, unfortunately. It was published in IEEE Information Theory Transactions, probably in the 90s or early 00s.

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/272494 this is it. Relations between entropy and error probability, Feder and Merhav. IT Transactions 1994. There are pdf's freely available elsewhere as well.